# Compile to Android

Tags: go

I wrote the below `build.go` to automate cross compiling process, but it fail `Android`, what could be the reason:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

type compiles struct {
    sys  string
    arch string
}

func main() {
    var output string
    // go tool dist list
    systems := []compiles{
        compiles{
            sys:  "darwin",
            arch: "amd64",
        },
        compiles{
            sys:  "android",
            arch: "amd64",
        },
        compiles{
            sys:  "linux",
            arch: "amd64",
        },
        compiles{
            sys:  "windows",
            arch: "amd64",
        },
    }

    for _, s := range systems {
        os.Setenv("GOOS", s.sys)
        os.Setenv("GOARCH", s.arch)
        switch println(s.sys); s.sys {
        case "darwin":
            output = "output.dmg"
        case "windows":
            output = "output.exe"
        case "android", "linux":
            output = "output"
        default:
            println("Undefined")
        }
        cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "-o", output, "main.go")
        out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("cmd.Run() failed with %v:\n\noutput:\n\n%s\n", err, out)
        }
    }
}
```

I got the below output:

```sh
C:\Users\hasan\Documents\GoPlay\Env>go run build.go
darwin
android
cmd.Run() failed with exit status 2:

output:

# command-line-arguments
c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'


linux
windows
```

I tried same at Mac OS, and got:

```sh
cmd.Run() failed with exit status 2:

output:

# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: unknown option: -z
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And tried at Linux (Ubuntu WSL at Win10) and got:

```sh
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `x_cgo_callers'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x8): undefined reference to `x_cgo_init'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x10): undefined reference to `x_cgo_mmap'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x18): undefined reference to `x_cgo_munmap'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x20): undefined reference to `x_cgo_notify_runtime_init_done'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x28): undefined reference to `x_cgo_sigaction'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x30): undefined reference to `x_cgo_thread_start'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x38): undefined reference to `x_cgo_setenv'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x40): undefined reference to `x_cgo_unsetenv'
/tmp/go-link-178415548/go.o:(.data+0x48): undefined reference to `_cgo_yield'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you sure you want your `GOARCH` to be `amd64` vs `arm64`?  Also how is `println` defined (.. is this a typo instead of `fmt.Println`?)

Comment: use, `Printf` instead of `Println` or `println`, what you are seeing is a pointer to the error. not the actual error string.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile? Also the example can be minimized to `GOOS="android" GOARCH="amd64" go build -o output main.go`

Comment: @jakub same error, my code is nothing but automating the same for multiple system.

Comment: @HasanAYousef - yes, I am saying that `go build` command reproduces the error. It seems like to build for Android (and iOS), you need to go through more steps than just `go build`. The https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile wiki explains how to build for Android.